# How to send additional information while posting video data in actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm now saving the snapshot this way:

```
            vidBmpHolder.draw(main.media.videoLocal);
            var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(85);
            var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(vidBmpHolder);
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://domain.name/savesnapshot.php");
            request.requestHeaders.push(header);
            request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            request.data = jpgStream;
            loader.load(request);
```

But I want to save additional information :

```
key=value
```

Is there a work around?

Comment: could you please show me how does the savesnapshot.php looks like? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add the key value pair at the url, for instance:

```
new URLRequest("http://domain.name/savesnapshot.php?filename=image1.jpg");
```

and then, on the php side:

```
$file_name = $_GET['filename'];
```

EDIT: Added server side php script.

```
<?php

$file_name = "image.jpg";

//here you access your file name passed in the url.
if( isset( $_GET["filename"] ) ) $file_name = $_GET["filename"];

$file = fopen($file_name, "w+") or die("Can't open file");

//here you access the bytearray data send form flash
$image_bytes = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

//create the image file
$fwrite = fwrite( $file, $image_bytes );

if ($fwrite === false) echo "Error writing to file: ".$file_name;

fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: How to retrieve the image data then?

Comment: @fms: You would use post as you did before. I will edit the answer to include the php side script, or a quick example at least.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to use [URLVariables](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html).

```
var variables : URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.foo= "foo";
variables.bar = "bar";
variables.jpgStream = Base64.encodeByteArray(jpgStream);
request.data = variables;
```

Note the Base64 encoding, and choose an appropriate library to do this.  This should eliminate the need for the header you set.

Then everything should appear as

```
$foo = $_POST["foo"];
$bar = $_POST["bar"];
$jpgStream = base64_decode($_POST["jpgStream"]);
```

You may need to do this as multipart, though.  Search around for the AS3 UploadPostHelper class, which contains an example.

Comment: Why `Base64` is necessary here?

Comment: Normal POSTs are sent as content-type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' when you have key/value pairs, so all key values are supposed to be URL encoded.  Base64 accomplishes this if you have binary data, and prevents URLVariables from percent encoding all the binary data.  The best way to handle large blobs of binary data, though, is do the post as multipart.  To accomplish this in AS3, you need a class like UploadPostHelper since calculating all of the boundaries is a pain.